# How Do I Run 2 Separate Instances of Tomcat Concurrently in the Same Eclpse Instance?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have Tomcat 8.5 set up on my current project. I have been told (and can't change), that I need to have 2 servers running 2 separate instances of Tomcat down to 2 separate file structures, property files, etc.

I can get one server to point to the first runtime environment.  When I point the second server to the second runtime environment, it saves both of them to the same runtime.

I need them to run concurrently, but be separate specific instances, within one Eclipse workspace.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be extremely helpful?

Comment: did you try to run them on different ports ?

Comment: Yes, and actually I figured it out. 

I deleted the second instance, added it back, and apparently could add the runtime from creation without causing the issue. If I create the server, and then try to add the new runtime, it will save both as the same.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured it out a few minutes later.

I deleted the second instance, and then created it again from scratch.

There is an option to add a new runtime environment during creation and I did that. This will add the 2nd runtime to the drop down in the Overview for the server settings. From there I was able to select it without it overwriting the first.